# SSL, Google Chrome & "non-secure" pages / forms

Tags: google-chrome, security, ssl, lets-encrypt

Google [states in their security blog](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/09/moving-towards-more-secure-web.html) that they will be starting in 2017 to mark

> "*HTTP pages that collect passwords or credit cards as non-secure, as part of a long-term plan to mark all HTTP sites as non-secure.*"

Since our pages are only incorporating email-signup-forms I am unsure as to whether this concerns us at all and/or we should be thinking about adding an SSL-certificate in order to render our user-entries safe(r).

Besides some SEO-benefits and HTTPS posing a requirement for making use of HTTP/2 I am wondering when might be the right time to include a SSL-certificate – what are your experiences and thoughts on this? What other technical aspects work into this?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Google security blog:

> Eventually, we plan to label all HTTP pages as non-secure, and change
>   the HTTP security indicator to the red triangle that we use for broken
>   HTTPS

Therefore it is wise to migrate from plain HTTP to HTTPS, and to implement an HSTS policy to enforce the use of HTTPS on your site. The policy tells the client to always connect over HTTPS, even if a malicious party tries to downgrade the connection to plain HTTP in order to sniff cookies.

As for the January 2017 change, I would surmise that Chrome would be looking for `<input type="password"...` fields or forms that appear to collect card numbers (e.g. field names commonly used on such forms) to decide whether to display the warning.

Comment: OK, I get that it is advisable to secure the page connections in general but the client isn't into that as of yet... 

Taken from your answer there most probably won't be a check for email form fields since this isn't considered sensitive data.

Guess we'll continue to run on HTTP until the standards are more set.